# What is the point of setting TESTOPTS="-v" with `rake test`?

Tags: ruby, testing, rake, minitest

I'm using `rake/testtask` in my app to generate the conventional `:test` task.

The examples demonstrate adding TESTOPTS="-v" to the command to turn on "verbose" mode:

```
rake test TESTOPTS="-v"             # run in verbose mode
```

(http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rake/Rake/TestTask)

Now, I've looked at the source code for `rake/testtask`, as well as wrote some code to test behaviour.  It's passing that env var on to the shell process it invokes to run the test file (via ruby command), and I can see the value set inside my test file.

However, what is it for?  Who is intended to receive/use it?

I'm currently using minitest, and it doesn't affect behaviour.  In fact, I searched the minitest repo for any instance of "testopts" and found nothing:

https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=testopts

So, is this a Test::Unit or RSpec feature?  Is no one currently hooking into this option?  Why isn't any of this explained in the docs?

Comment: Just noticed the TESTFILE option doesn't do anything, either.

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/583

Answer (score 1):

It shows you how much time each test takes and which test blocks the testing.